# How can I debug why Slurm isn't preempting lower priority jobs?

Tags: slurm

I have a single slurm partition, with a bunch of nodes, currently all occupied. I can see with `squeue` that there are a lot of (newer) pending jobs with higher QoS priorities than the currently running jobs. How do I figure out why Slurm isn't preempting them?

A snippet from my `slurm.conf`:

```
# PREEMPTION
PreemptType=preempt/qos
PreemptMode=REQUEUE

# PRIORITY 
PriorityType=priority/multifactor
PriorityCalcPeriod=0-1:00:00
PriorityDecayHalfLife=0-0:1:00
PriorityWeightFairshare=0
PriorityWeightAge=0
PriorityWeightPartition=0
PriorityWeightJobSize=0
PriorityWeightQOS=10000
PriorityMaxAge=7-0

PartitionName=regular   Nodes=snod[01-64],bsnod[01-18] Shared=NO Priority=100 Default=YES
```

Is there some kind of log where I can see it doing preemption checks or something?
Thank you!

Comment: How are QOS'es defined?

Answer (score 0):

The `slurm.conf` file has an option `DebugFlags` which you should set to `Priority,Backfill,SelectType`. Also make sure the option `SlurmctldDebug` is set to `verbose` or `debug`. Then you can find the logs in the file referred to in `SlurmctldLogFile`.